# How to export svg images as <img ...> in html export

Tags: org-mode, org-export, html

Normally, when I export to html an `org-mode` buffer that contains a
link to an image, the link is coverted to a proper html `<img...>`.
However, if that image has a `.svg` extension, it is exported as an `<object...>` instead.

How do I prevent this?

For instance, the following link:

```
[[file:https://clojars.org/malabarba/lazy-map/latest-version.svg]]
```

gets exported like this:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="https://clojars.org/malabarba/lazy-map/latest-version.svg" >
Sorry, your browser does not support SVG.</object>
```

But I'd like it to be exported like this:

```
<img src="https://clojars.org/malabarba/lazy-map/latest-version.svg">
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a `:fallback` attribute almost does it:

```
#+ATTR_HTML: :fallback /tmp/toto.svg
[[file:/tmp/toto.svg]]
```

is exported as:

```
<div class="figure">
<p><object type="image/svg+xml" data="file:///tmp/toto.svg" >
<img src="/tmp/toto.svg"  /></object>
</p>
</div>
```

Otherwise, it seems easy to redefine or advice `org-html--format-image` in `ox-html.el` (for some reason, it treats svg's specially).

Comment: Thanks. If no-one knows a configuration option for this, I'll just have to advise that function.

Comment: @Malabarba can you show us how you advised it?

Comment: It works great! How have you discovered that?